# How write into CSV file properly

Tags: ruby, csv

i am using ruby 1.9.2 and also use its csv library.I want to write in csv properly just

like this

```
name,country_code,destination,code
Afghanistan,93,Bamain,51
Afghanistan,93,Bamain,52
Afghanistan,93,Bamain,53
Afghanistan,93,Parwan,91
```

My code is this

```
def export_data
  @coun = Country.all(:limit => 10)
  header = "name,country_code,destination,code"
  file = "my_file.csv"
  File.open(file, "w") do |csv|
    csv << header
    @coun.each do |c|
      csv << [c.name, c.country_code, c.user_id, c.subscriber_id]       
      # How puts line break here
    end
  end
  send_file(file)
end
```

I have mention above how puts i line break there in CSV file and also omit this sigh which

covers every row in CSV"[]"

```
 Like   ["Finland",1,1,2334]
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
csv << "\n"
```

Stackoverflow requires 30 characters in an answer, but I don't know what more to say.

Comment: using the csv write as proposed by @abrukish avoids you some headaches with values containing commas.

Answer (score 78):

I think general CSV writer will be good enough for you:

```
require 'csv'
file = "my_file.csv"
CSV.open( file, 'w' ) do |writer|
  @coun.each do |c|
    writer << [c.name, c.country_code, c.user_id, c.subscriber_id]
  end
end
```