# Writing to CSV returns : undefined method `map' for "\n" or "0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am trying to write to a CSV but i ran into a problem. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702895/how-write-into-csv-file-properly) so I have just applied the solution but I get an error. 
This is my code:

```
require 'csv'

data = Owner.find(2).cats
CSV.open("file.csv", "w") do |csv|
  data.each do |cat|
    csv << cat.name
  end
end
```

I have checked in console and I am getting data `for Owner.find(2).cats`.
When trying to write this to my `CSV` i get the error:

> undefined method `map' for 0:Fixnum

and when I try the simple solution from the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702895/how-write-into-csv-file-properly) :

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("file.csv", "w") do |csv|
    csv << "\n"
end
```

I get this error:

> undefined method `map' for "\n":String

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

I am new to ruby so maybe I am doing one of the roockie  mistakes

Comment: What is `Data`?  What does `Data.find()` return?  What does `.cats` return?

Comment: @MarkReed I have changed so it is maybe easier to understand.
`Owner` has a relationship with `cats`. `Owner` has_many: `cats` . And cats have `name` , `age` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSV is a collection of rows, each of which is a collection of columns; it's a two-dimensional array, that gets converted to text form. So the top-level `CSV` object expects you to append arrays to it, not individual cell values.

Note that in this code:

```
CSV.open('filename','w') do |csv|
   do stuff
end
```

The `do stuff` is only run exactly once. It's up to you to create the structure of the CSV, usually with something like this:

```
CSV.open('filename','w') do |csv|
  data.each |item|
    row = [item.field1, item.field2, item.field3]
    csv << row
  end
end
```

or even a double loop:

```
CSV.open('filename','w') do |csv|
  data.each |item|
    row = []
    fields.each do |field|
       row << item[field]
    end
    csv << row
  end
end
```

As an example:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'csv' #=> true
irb(main):002:0> CSV.open("cats.csv", "w") do |csv|
irb(main):003:1* csv << [ "cat1" ] << [ "cat2" ] << [ "cat3 " ]
irb(main):004:1> end
#=> <#CSV io_type:File io_path:"cats.csv" encoding:UTF-8 lineno:3 col_sep:"," row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"">
irb(main):005:0>
$ cat cats.csv
cat1
cat2
cat3
$
```

Notice that the file has no quotation marks or square brackets in it.

Comment: Thank you,  but know everything has `"something" ` when i write to csv :/

Comment: What are you planing to do with this CSV file?  Any spreadsheet program will parse it properly with the quotation marks.

Comment: I want it to be readable in excel, and when I open it everything is in one line and has `"[[ something"` `" something " `"something]]"` format

Comment: Are you looking at the file or at the CSV object?  Seeing brackets when inspecting it in Ruby is expected; if you see brackets in the actual file written out by `CSV`, then something has gone terribly wrong.

Comment: Include actual code used to create the file... your code in this question does not result in any brackets in the CSV file unless the cat names have brackets in them.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed my other issue. I was using `send_data` not `send_file`. Thank you again for helping me and explaining evetything

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'csv'

data = Owner.find(2).cats
CSV.open("file.csv", "w") do |csv|
  data.each { |cat| csv << [cat.name] }
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this is working and why `csv << "\n" ` does not work. In the question that i linked to it has 52 upvotes.

Comment: Additionaly this puts  `[[ "name_of_cat" ]]` in the csv , not just `name_of_cat`

Comment: @kemis You need to add an array, not a single string. `[ "\n" ]` would work.

Comment: @kemis If you look carefully at that answer you see an array is constructed first, and then the array is added using `<<`. It's correct. This answer is equally correct and is a more minimal solution.

Comment: @tadman the accepted answer is `csv << "\n"` , just this line , where is he constructing an array?

Comment: @kemis What answer are you looking at? It says `csv << row`.

Comment: @kemis is talking about the question linked above, not this one. It does appear to have an incorrect answer indicating that you can do `csv << "\n"`.

Comment: @kemis The CSV module in Ruby was significantly updated in 1.9 so this may be why older answers that took advantage of that sort of quirky behaviour no longer work. These answers here are how you should do it, regardless of how it could have been done in the past.